# Select template for execution using a condition including variable on apply-templates

Tags: xslt, variables

I have a template that looks like below

> **<xsl:template match="more-info" mode="docuSection">
>   html
>   </xsl:template>**

and which is applied with the call

> **<xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="docuSection"/>**

so the template is applied when the current node has **more-info** element, is there a way to make this template get applied with the same call and with the condition which includes a global variable e.g. match="$mode='edit' or more-info"

Best Regards,
Keshav

Comment: Good question: +1. See my answer for explanation and complete solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way to make this template
>   get applied with the same call and
>   with the condition which includes a
>   global variable e.g.
>   match="$mode='edit' or more-info"

**In XSLT 2.0 this is perfectly legal**:

```
<xsl:template match="more-info[$mode = ('edit', 'more-info')]"
mode="docuSection">
```

**In XSLT 1.0 it is forbidden** to use variable or key references within a match pattern.

**However, one can use either of the following techniques**:

I. Within the `<xsl:apply-templates>` instruction specify the exact node-list of nodes to be processed.

```
<xsl:apply-templates mode="docuSection" 
     select="self::*[$mode = 'edit' or $mode='more-info']" />
```

||. Make the match pattern more general, but do any processing within the template only if the desired condition is fulfilled:

```
<xsl:template match="more-info" mode="docuSection">
 <xsl:if test="$mode = 'edit' or $mode='more-info'">
    html
 </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```